# How to look at 2KHz to 2.5KHz with a 1024 FFT

Tags: fft

I've tried searching for an answer to this, but i don't think i'm looking for the right thing. Lets say i wanted to examine a signal in the frequency domain that's between 2K-2.5KHz. Can i do this with a FFT smaller than 8192, for example 1024? I understand that if i took an FFT of 8192 that i could see the signals in bins 2000 through 2500. Is there a way to take a smaller FFT, or multiple smaller FFTs in order to achieve this. I don't really care what the signal looks like outside of this range. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: You need to consider the frequency at which the data is sampled in order to scale the x-axis of the FFT and make sense of the frequencies you are looking at.  You must also understand that the FFT is two-sided and symmetrical.  A 1024 point FFT should be sufficient. Good luck to you.

Comment: As CMDoolittle pointed out 1024 FFT is sufficient.. Please mention to us the sampling rate or sampling frequency.

Comment: You can answer your own questions by studying the discrete Fourier transform (DFT).  The FFT is merely a fast way to compute DFTs.  You need to learn how the input time data's samples rate (samples/second or Hz) and how the DFT (FFT) size affect your DFT results.

Comment: For practical matters, sample at 5,000 samples per second. The FFT result will contain the 2-2.5 Khz range in bins 2000 to 2500 (roughly) of the 1024 point FFT.

Comment: I was planning on sampling at 32768 samples/sec, then decimate (which i haven't figured out the best decimating method) to 8192. I'm wanting to look at the amplitude and phase at the frequencies between 2K and 2.5K every 1 Hz, so i'll be looking at 500 different frequencies. Is DFT still the best option for this and if so, should i still try to decimate the samples? If I understand correctly, doing a 1024 FFT on a 8192 decimated sample rate i would only be able to see every 8th Hz. Is that correct? Thanks for all the input!